# Is there any way to get all country,state and cities mysql data ? (a dump file)

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a project and I need a database or MySQL table of list of countries, states and cities.

I need a free one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This question has been answered many times on StackOverflow, but here are several resources:

- http://www.maxmind.com/en/worldcities
- http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite
- http://www.geodatasource.com/cities-free.html
- http://www.geonames.org/export/

Github for sql files
https://github.com/hiiamrohit/Countries-States-Cities-database

---

**edit:**

User @Juan Escobar suggested in an edit that another source for such data is 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/world-setup/en/index.html
But that's just an example database provided by MySQL.com. I don't think it's intended to be comprehensive or current.

That database is derived from data available at [Statistics Finland](http://tilastokeskus.fi/tup/kvportaali/kv_tiedonlahteet_en.html), so that may be a better source for current data.

Comment: This github link is more current: https://github.com/dr5hn/countries-states-cities-database.git

Comment: Many of the links are not valid, please remove them